# Reactivation of iPhone5

Tags: iphone

My phone was suddenly deactivated about two weeks ago. I had turned my phone off because I was flying from Auckland NZ to risbane, Aust. When I turned my phone on again, it said it had been deactivated.

> Your iPhone could not be activated because the activation server cannot be reached. Try connecting your iPhone to iTunes to activate it or tr again over the mobile connection in a couple of minutes. You can also try to reactivate using a wi-fi connection

I contacted Apple in Brisbane, and they were no help, and I spent about 40 minutes on the phone to the Melbourne help centre, and they were unable to help me either.
How can I get my phone reactivated?

Comment: Did the phone get deactivated or the SIM card? Can you add a screenshot/picture of the message you are seeing on the phone?

Comment: it says 'Your iPhone could not be activated because the activation server cannot be reached. Try connecting your iPhone to iTunes to activate it or tr again over the mobile connection in a couple of minutes. You can also try to reactivate using a wi-fi connection.

Comment: I assume you did try with a wi-fi connection? What did the Apple support try to do to resolve it?

Comment: One of the problems is that I cannot remember my password for iTunes, but when I tried to rest my password, it only gave me the option of having it sent to my phone---which has been deactivated! I visited the Apple store in Brisbane Australia, and they were no help at all, and I called the support people in Melbourne Australia, talked for about 40 minutes, and they couldn't help either. What I would really like to know is why it happened in the first place.

Comment: I live in New Zealand.